# Transfering money from one stripe account to another in test mode

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am having difficulties when I try to apply the transfer method so I need your help.

What I want to do is transfer money [IN TEST MODE]  from one stripe account to another, I did the exact thing that was written in the documentation looks like this:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: '2020-03-02',
  maxNetworkRetries: 2,
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 100,
      currency: 'eur',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      transfer_group: '{ORDER10}',
    });

    // Create a Transfer to the connected account (later):
    await stripe.transfers.create({
      amount: 70,
      currency: 'eur',
      destination: '{{ACCOUNT_ID}}',
      transfer_group: '{ORDER10}',
    });

   


    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(paymentIntent),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({ error });

    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    };
  }
};
```

What I am getting is an error with saying there is no such destination, which means that the account ID is not available.

I got my other stripe account's ID with the curl command:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/account -u {{SK_TEST_KEY}}
```

this gave me the ID and that's what I pasted in the `{{ACCOUNT_ID}}` field.

What am I doing wrong? Is it something that this thing can not be done in test mode?

Or somehow I need to connect both of my stripe accounts??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you creating the Payment Intent and Transfer objects using the API keys of the **platform** (application) account? Also, the account ID you are passing to the `destination` parameter must be [connected](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts) (onboarded) to the same platform account.

Comment: oh so it wont work in test mode right? or  being connected doesn't have to do anything with being testmode?    I am guessing to be connected you need give some live data such as your real card, business info

Comment: The destination account still needs to be connected to the platform in order to transfer in test mode, yes. You can use the [dummy data](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing) for onboarding in test mode.

Comment: excuse my ignorance but what connected to the same platform exactly mean? How do I connect them to the same platform.

Comment: You have a Stripe account which you are creating the Payment Intent and Transfer objects on – this is the 'platform'. You need to connect/onboard the other account (the destination) you want to transfer the funds to to that platform account. You can learn about that process [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts).

Answer (score 0):

I created an account on my dashboard stripe page, the main thing was that it has to be a standard account, filled in with some dummy data which I found thanks to Jonathan Steele, after that the transfer worked.